# not found.Cell magic `%%time

Tags: python

This is LIME for image classification by using Keras. I am getting the above error

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
import os,sys
try:
    import lime
except:
    sys.path.append(os.path.join('..', '..')) # add the current directory
    import lime
from lime import lime_image

explainer = lime_image.LimeImageExplainer()

%%time
explanation = explainer.explain_instance(images[0], inet_model.predict, top_labels=5, hide_color=0, num_samples=1000)
```

Comment: Please format your question properly. I can't tell if there's a linebreak between `%%time` and `explanation`, for example.

Comment: Kindly go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so you can ask a batter quality question which will help to understand more about your problem :)

Answer (score 4):

as far as I can tell "Cell magics" must always be at the top of a cell, the only documentation I can find describing this behavior is when I enter `%magic` into iPython (or a Jupyter notebook cell)

> In the notebook, simply type the whole cell as one entity, but keep in mind that the %% escape can only be at the very start of the cell.

this appears in the source [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/a8165da9102a62203c824f8cb59988e188fc6032/IPython/core/magics/basic.py#L254) but I can't find this documented anywhere else

to fix this you'd just move the `%%time` magic into its own cell and it should be happy

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me. I had just renamed the notebook file from "Untitled" to "Basic IO".

Syntax was perfectly fine (I think); first cell of the notebook starting with

```
%%writefile test2.txt
line1
line2
```

Got the error:

> UsageError: Cell magic `%%` not found.

I did a Kernel Restart and ran it; it worked.

Not sure if this *the* right answer but it worked, so thought I'd share.

Answer (score 0):

The "Cell magics" function that you are loocking for is `%%timeit`.

Comment: Can you explain why this function and not the one that the OP used?